# Thymeleaf , JQuery and messages properties

Tags: java, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this message in my message.properties

```
resetPassword.sending.email=Sending email
```

I want to use it in the HTML,

```
$("#sendEmailButtonId").click(function(e) {
    $("#emailLabelId").text([[#{resetPassword.sending.email}]]);
});
```

but it does not replace the text

Comment: Do you have `<script th:inline="javascript">`?  What does the javascript look like when you view source?

Comment: no, I don't, I will set it

Comment: @Metroids , please convert to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<script th:inline="javascript">` in the surrounding script block for thymeleaf to parse `[[${...}]]` expressions.